# How can I change the font size of a row dynamically with datatables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I checked datatables [api](https://datatables.net/reference/api/) but couldn't see anything under row() functions. Basically I want to achieve this kind of functionality:

```
var myTable = $('#example').DataTable();
myTable.row(i).fontSize = dynamicValue;
```

Or

```
myTable.row(i).css('font-size', dynamicValue);
```

Comment: Why not use jQuery directly? `myTable.find('tr').eq(i).addClass('big-font');`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a persistent solution you *have* to go through the API. If you have a dataTable instance :

```js
var table = $('#example').DataTable()
```

and a CSS class :

```css
.larger-font {
  font-size: 120%;
}
```

then you can permanently change the `font-size` of a clicked row by :

```js
$('#example').on('click', 'tr', function() {
  table.row(this).nodes().to$().addClass('larger-font')
})
```

`row(this)` gives you the internal row instance
`nodes()` gives you the entire `<tr>` DOM node
`to$()` return that DOM node as jQuery instance
`addClass()` adds the CSS

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/tgefobbq/**

If you want to manipulate inline CSS instead of injecting classes you just do this the same way :

```
table.row(this).nodes().to$().css('font-size', '120%')
```

`to$()` is not necessary, just convenient - you can target the "raw" DOM as well :

```
table.row(this).nodes()[0].style.cssText = 'font-size:120%;
```

But either way, it is important you retrieve the DOM nodes through the API, not through jQuery or any other way.

Comment: I understand that this is for the particular rows.. but what if I wish to change the fonts of the whole datatable instead? I tried `tbl.addClass("my-class")` with `tbl` being my jquery variable. Should I open a new question instead?

Comment: @Malky.Kid, You should :) But here goes. Do this in CSS, here is an example  ->  `.dataTables_wrapper {  font-family: 'courier' !important; }`   The "trick" is to target the entire container, not just the `<table>` itself, so the font also is changed for the length menu and so on. Se it updated fiddle -> **http://jsfiddle.net/tgefobbq/26/**